# List not getting updated through async method

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code:

```
List<String> databaseEntryID = <String>[];

readAllData() async {
    await db.collection("users").get().then((event) {
      for (var doc in event.docs) {
        print(doc.id);
        databaseEntryID.add(doc.id);
      }
    });
  }

  readData() {
    final docRef = db.collection(databaseEntryID[0]).doc(databaseEntryID[1]);
    docRef.get().then(
          (res) => print("Successfully completed"),
      onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
    );
  }
```

If I call `readAllData()` first and then do `readData()` second, I get a RangeError: `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`.

I don't fully grasp how async works, so what am I doing wrong here, how do I get the list updated first, and then access the first and second String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this after searching, should've checked this first (I usually avoid doc pages as they're made too complex like, this one is guide like): https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

So the simplest fix is to:

```
List<String> databaseEntryID = <String>[];

readAllData() async {
    await db.collection("users").get().then((event) {
      for (var doc in event.docs) {
        print(doc.id);
        databaseEntryID.add(doc.id);
      }
    });
  }

  readData() async {
    await readAllData();

    final docRef = db.collection(databaseEntryID[0]).doc(databaseEntryID[1]);
    docRef.get().then(
          (res) => print("Successfully completed"),
      onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
    );
  }
```

Call the `readAllData` function from `readData` using the **await** keyword to show that it needs to wait for its return, and then execute the `readData` method (needs **async** modifier).

Answer (score 1):

For Async, I usually implement Listener Pattern. This way, when you receive data from async you can work with it. Basically what happens here is that you cann readData() before the readAllData() result arrives. What you could do/try to do to patch this is:
1.

```
readAllData() async {
    await db.collection("users").get().then((event) {
      for (var doc in event.docs) {
        print(doc.id);
        databaseEntryID.add(doc.id);
      }
      // Do here the things you might want to do when receiving an information (such as notifying the listeners..)
    });
  }
```

Or 2.

```
List<String> databaseEntryID = <String>[];
Boolean databaseHydrated = false;

readAllData() async {
    await db.collection("users").get().then((event) {
      for (var doc in event.docs) {
        print(doc.id);
        databaseEntryID.add(doc.id);
      }
      databaseHydrated = true;
    });
  }

  readData() {
    if(databaseHydrated) {
      final docRef = db.collection(databaseEntryID[0]).doc(databaseEntryID[1]);
      docRef.get().then(
            (res) => print("Successfully completed"),
        onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
      );
    } else {
      // Do whatever you want, like toggle a loading screen while waiting for async data ?
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: A boolean or within that same method, elegant solution! Thank you! I would've chosen this answer had I not just learnt about async methods, so I will leave my answer also. :)